# Как получить имя Workgroup в Windows?

Tags: java

Как получить имя Workgroup в Windows?

Comment: Поскольку Workgroup — Windows-специфическая штука, а Java нет, боюсь, вам придётся возиться с JNI.

Comment: VladD, спасибо! Я так и думал…( специфическая штука). Попробую  с JNI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем? ;) 
Ну, в принципе идеологически правильно проводить идентификацию пользователя при входе в приложение. В web после первичной идентификации пользователя при повторном обращении используются куки (либо "замена"). В десктопном приложении... покопайте в сторону получения системных переменных. Опять же в вопросе содержится слишком мало информации для получения развернутого ответа.

Comment: Для идентификации пользователя… Чтобы долго не рассказывать пользователю, как ему это определить...

Comment: barmaglott, спасибо! Приложения десктопное. Попробую порыть в сторону системных переменных.